# Bullet movement

Tags: android, andengine

I'm new at games development and now stalled at one problem.
Trying to make tower defence type game, For now i have made "tower" with some functions, and where is problem with firing bullets.

Idea: touch somewhere on screen and bullet fire that direction. (bullet starting pos in middle of screen, speed must be a constant)

Maybe somebody knows how to calc that direction which bullet should fire.
I think, should calc angle or something to get that direction...
i.e.

```
this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(angle*SPEED, angle*SPEED);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little bit if it's 2D or 3D but the idea is basically the same.

I would start by making a Vector class which has to variables, x and y. I would then add a few method for adding and subtracting Vectors. What you would have to do then would be to subtract from the touchPosition Vector the firingPosition Vector which would give you the direction Vector towards which you have to shoot.

If you need more help with this just comment.

Comment: its 2D game, for instace i calculated vector between touch pos and starting pos, what i should do next?

Comment: I think you have to do this: `this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(vector.x*SPEED, vector.y*SPEED);`. Can you please tell me how the method setVelocity() works?

Comment: setVelocity(x,y) 
x - how much move on X axis on every update
y - how much move on Y axis on every update

Comment: Then it should work with what I said earlier: `this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(vector.x*SPEED, vector.y*SPEED);`.(vector is the vector that you calculated, touch pos - starting pos)